# Matlab: binomial simulation

Tags: matlab

How do i simulate a binomial distribution with values for investment with two stocks acme and widget?
Number of trials is 1000
invest in each stock for 5 years

This is my code.  What am I doing wrong?

```
nyears = 5;
ntrials = 1000;
startamount = 100;
yrdeposit = 50;

acme = zeros(nyears, 1);
widget = zeros(nyears,1);
v5 = zeros(ntrials*5, 1);
v5 = zeros(ntrials*5, 1);

%market change between -5 to 1%
marketchangeacme = (-5+(1+5)*rand(nyears,1));
marketchangewidget = (-3+(3+3)*rand(nyears,1));

acme(1) = startamount;
widget(1) = startamount;

for m=1:numTrials

   for n=1:nyears
      acme(n) = acme(n-1) + (yrdeposit * (marketchangeacme(n)));
      widget(n) = acme(n-1) + (yrdeposit * (marketchangewidget(n)));
      vacme5(i) = acme(j);
      vwidget5(i) = widget(j);
   end

   theMean(m) = mean(1:n*nyears);

   p = 0.5 % prob neg return
   acmedrop = (marketchangeacme < p)
   widgetdrop = (marketchangewidget <p)
end

plot(mean)
```

Comment: Why do you think something is wrong here?

Comment: i think the modeling and vector sizes are not correct but i dont know how to fix it.  my plot does not converge as i expected.  First i calculate the returns after 5 years.  then i need to run the trial 1000 times.  When should i take the average return for the plotting?  I dont know if my binomial model p is correct.   I am so confused :(    can someone offer some guidance so i can carry on minus frustration?

Answer (score 1):

Exactly what you are trying to calculate is not clear.  However some things that are obviously wrong with the code are:

1. `widget(n)` presumable isn't a function of `acme(n-1)` but rather 'widget(n-1)`
2. Every entry of `theMean` will be `mean(1:nyears*nyears)`, which for `nyears=5` will be `13`.  (This is because `n=nyears` always at that point in code.)
3. The probability of a negative return for acme is 5/6, not 0.5.
4. To find the locations of the negative returns you want `acmedrop = (marketchangeacme < 0);` not `< 0.5` (nor any other probability).  Similarly for widgetdrop.
5. You are not preallocating `vacme5` nor `vwidget5` (but you do preallocate `v5` twice, and then never use it.
6. You don't create a variable called `mean` (and you never should) so `plot(mean)` will not work.